# Problem on Triangles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

I was solving this question. I solved it. Then I forgot how I solved it.

> An acute angled triangle $ABC$ has $AD$ as altitude. $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$. $F$ is the midpoint of $AC$. $\angle{EAB}=40°$ and $\angle{EAD}=\angle{EFD}$. Find $\angle{ADF}$.

This is the diagram I made.
[image: Made by a Pen]

What I cannot understand is how I proved $\angle{AEF}=\angle{ADF}$, or if that is even true, and how to actually get the solution.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The points $A$, $F$, $E$, and $D$ are concyclic because $A$ and $F$ subtends equal angles with respect to the segment $ED$ that is $\angle{EAD}=\angle{EFD}$. Moreover $EF$ is parallel to $AB$ because $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle FEC$ are similar. 
Hence 
$$40^{\circ}=\angle{EAB}=\angle{AEF}=\angle{ADF}$$
where in the last equality we used the fact that $A$, $F$, $E$, and $D$ are concyclic and therefore  $E$ and $D$ subtends equal angles with respect to the segment $AF$.

Comment: I knew that... But how does that help?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo I edited my answer with more details.

Comment: Fuu says thanks. Tobi is a good boy.

Answer (score 3):

$40^{\circ}$ because $AEDF$ is cyclic and $EF||AB$.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo $E$ and $F$ are midpoints of $BC$ and $AC$ respectively. Thus, $EF||AB$.

Comment: No, I know the midpoint theorem. But how do the parallelism(?) of the lines and a concyclic quadrilateral come together to give 40°?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo They are alternate angles.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg (+1) For the hints.

Comment: @Robert Z Thank you! Our solutions are same. +1 from me too.